# text as a border character by gradation (Android)

Tags: android, text, border

On the development of Android.
I want to display text as a border character by gradation.
If it's just a gradation I can do it with a shader. However, it does not display correct answers with bordering there.

What should I do?

Comment: What are you doing this with? TextView? Button? Canvas? OpenGL? And where is your current code?

Comment: hi!  textView is

Comment: using styles.xml with a drawable .xml resource you can do this. Look at the android documentation for more details

Comment: thanks. I want to write gradation code. Does style.xml need a gradation png ?

Comment: It can a drawable .xml resource, doesnt have to be .png